# nullmailer: Sending failed: Could not exec program

Tags: email, mail-transport-agent

I'm trying to set up `nullmailer` with Google Apps. I think I have properly configured Google Apps and `/etc/nullmailer/remotes`, but somehow I'm getting this error

> Sending failed: Could not exec program

Here's a bit more verbosity:

```
# sudo -u mail nullmailer-send
Rescanning queue.
Starting delivery, 1 message(s) in queue.
Starting delivery: protocol: --port=587 host: smtp-relay.gmail.com file: 1470693591.47284
Sending failed: Could not exec program
Delivery complete, 1 message(s) remain.
```

And my `remotes`:

```
sudo cat /etc/nullmailer/remotes
smtp-relay.gmail.com --port=587 --starttls
```

(I have Google Apps relay access configured by IP, not user/pass.)

Comment: You should show your `remotes` file (properly redacted for username/password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the solution by using `strace` on the nullmailer daemon process. It tried to execute `/usr/lib/nullmailer/--starttls` which lead me to double-check the `remotes` file format and have a look at that directory.

**The solution is to add `smtp`** to your `remotes` line:

```
smtp-relay.gmail.com smtp --port=587 --starttls
```